# IE11 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, tailwind-css

I got the following error using internet explorer 11.

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
> lato-v16-latin-100italic.eot

This is how I included it to `fonts.css`

```
/* lato-100italic - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Lato Hairline Italic'), local('Lato-HairlineItalic'),
    url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.svg#Lato') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I followed https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts to include the fonts.

What can I do to solve this issue? I understand that comment `src: url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */`  that this is going to *prevent* errors in IE9..?

Comment: It looks like if the user is using the IE 9 compatibility mode then the above code will download the .eot file to support it. I tried to run the above sample code but I did not get any error in the IE 11 browser. If possible then you can try to share the example that can reproduce the error. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. For more information you can try to refer to this [document](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).